# How do I ensure 'read_excel' on Pandas reads the correct sheet?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

The following piece of code is getting the data from Excel in the 5th row and the 14th row:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymssql
df=[]
fp = "G:\\Data\\Hotels\\ABZPD - Daily Strategy Tool.xlsm" 
data = pd.read_excel(fp,sheet_name ="CRM View" )
row_date = data.loc[2, :]
row_sita = "ABZPD"
row_event = data.iloc[11, :]

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': row_date,
                           'sita': row_sita,
                           'event': row_event
                           })
print(df)
```

However, it is not actually using the worksheet I need it to. Instead of using "CRM View" (like I told it to!) it is using the worksheet "Previous CRM View". I assume this is because both worksheets have similar names.

So the question is, how do I get it to use the one that is called "CRM View"?

Comment: Not sure why you have this problem, but you can try integer-based indexing of sheets instead.

Comment: @IanS There's alot of sheets in the workbook so I would rather refer to them by name

Comment: Why tag it “excel” - it’s not an excel issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem. It didn't seem like it was about that the supplied sheet name is similar, it just read the first sheet in the file no matter what you put `sheet_name` to.

Anyway, It seemed like a bug so I checked what version of `pandas` I was running, which was `0.20.3`. After updating to `0.22.0` the problem was gone and the right sheet was selected.

Edit: this was apparently a [known bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17107) in `0.20.3`.

Comment: It was definitely a UI bug, but to be fair, the documentation points out it's `sheetname`, not `sheet_name`.